# Mysterious for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, sequence, contains, membership

Let `exp = [1,2,3,4,5]`

If I then execute `x in exp`, it will give me `False`. But if I execute :

```
for x in exp:
    if x==3:
        print('True')
```

Then execute `x in exp`, it returns `True`. What's happening here? I didn't assign anything to x.  Did I?   I am really confused.

**EDIT:**Sorry if I didn't say this before: `x` is not defined before.

#### Answer

Thank you everyone. I understand it now. the elements of `exp` is assigned to `x` as `exp` is iterated over. And `x in exp` equals `True` in the last line of code because the last element has been assigned to `x`.

Comment: if you execute `x in exp` first, it will give you a `NameError`, not `False`.

Comment: Nothing is returning anything in this code

Comment: The answer must be: `x` was bound to a value that wasn't in `exp` before. You didn't tell us about the state of `x` before you ran the `for` loop however.

Comment: For those voting to close: there's a pretty clear question here (imho) regarding whether loops do assignments. I don't think this necessarily needs closing.

Comment: Agreed with Amber. It's not a perfectly-written question (the red herring in the second sentence definitely isn't helping), but there's a real question here. Unless it's a dup, I don't think there's any reason to close it.

Comment: Mr E, can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Seems like you stumbled about `in` being somewhat overloaded in Python.

- with [`x in exp`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in), you are asking "Is `x` **in** `exp`?"
- with [`for x in exp: ...`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement), you tell Python "**For** each element **in** `exp`, call it `x` and do ..."

The latter will assign each of the values in `exp` to `x`, one after the other, and execute the body of the loop with that value, so in the first iteration `x` is assigned `1`, in the second `2`, and in the last `5`. Also, `x` *keeps* this value after the loop!

Thus, before the loop, assuming that the variable `x` is defined but has some other value, `x in exp` will return `False`, and after the loop, it returns `True`, because `x` is still assigned the last value from `exp`.

Comment: +1, especially with links to the grammar that defines the dual uses of `in`.

Answer (score 7):

`for x in ...` inherently assigns values to `x`, because `x` is the loop variable in [a `for` loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Each iteration of the loop assigns a value into `x`; Python doesn't create a new variable scope for loops.

```
for x in (1, 2, 3):
    foo(x)
```

is the equivalent of...

```
x = 1
foo(x)
x = 2
foo(x)
x = 3
foo(x)
```

Comment: Nice answer. One minor point to make (which the OP won't even understand, but which might be useful to other readers who find this via search): A list comprehension looks a lot like a `for` loop (because it is one), but it _does_ create a new variable scope (but only in 3.x—in 2.x, generator expressions create new scopes, other comprehensions don't).

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is similar, but they mean two different things.

`x in exp` is a conditional expression; it searches to see if the value
of `x` appears in the list `exp`. If it's there, the expression
evaluates to `True`, otherwise, `False`. You can also use `not in`.

`for x in exp` introduces a loop where `x` iterates over the elements of
`exp`. The loop body will be called once for each element, and within
the body, `x` will be set to each element successively.

Comment: ["Conditional expression"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) in Python means `eggs if spam else beans`, not `eggs in spam`. (There probably is an official name for the latter besides "in comparison expression", but it's not coming to me off the top of my head.)

Comment: @abarnert "Membership test."

Comment: Sorry, I meant an expression used in a conditional context, or something. I've always been better at using the stuff than remembering what it's called.

Answer (score 1):

That's how looping works in Python. '`For var in sequence`' will assign to `var` as you iterate through the sequence.

If you were to simply print `x` for example:

```
for x in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    print x
```

You would see the following:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Perhaps what you were looking for was just the index of the value? If so, there are a couple of things you could do.

To iterate explicitly with the index, use `enumerate(sequence)` as such:

```
for index, x in enumerate(mylist):
    if index == 3:
        do_stuff()
```

Where the first value (`index` in this case) will always be the index of the current iteration.

You can also iterate over the length of the object using `range(len(sequence))` which is sometimes useful if you're potentially modifying the list as you iterate. Here you're actually creating a separate list using `range`, with length equal to the `len` of the list. This will *not* assign from the list you're targeting -- rather it will assign from the list created by `range()` -- so you'd have to access it using your `for x in...` as the index of the list.

```
for x in range(len(mylist)):
    if mylist[x] == 3:
        things_and_stuff()
```

As for your second line and point of confusion - 'x in exp' - you will indeed see that `x` remains assigned after the fact, and so using `x in exp` will return `True` because the last assigned value to `x` is, in fact, in `exp`.

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for x in mylist:
...     print x
... 
1
2
3
>>> x
3
>>> x in mylist
True
```

Comment: The last one has an even bigger problem than the ones you mentioned. In `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`, `mylist.index(mylist[3])` isn't `3`, it's `0`. This is the source of hundreds of Stack Overflow and python-list questions…

Comment: Yes, the last one is awful. I hesitated suggesting it, and maybe I'll just remove it altogether if the OP doesn't realize that `for x in sequence` is assigning in this way.

Comment: In fact, yeah deleted

Answer (score 1):

When you run your first loop, a variable `x` is assigned to each value of the list as you iterate over it.

Let's say you start with `x=0`.

`0` **is not** in `[1,2,3,4,5]`, therefore `x in exp = False`.

However, when you run the loop, you now have a new `x`. When the loop is complete, `x` is initialized to the final element in the list, meaning `x=5`.

`5` **is** in `[1,2,3,4,5]`, therefore `x in exp = True`.

Comment: Thanks. I now know why `x in exp = True`.