# Python 'in' keyword in expression vs. in for loop

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, semantics

I understand what the `in` operator does in this code:

```
some_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(2 in some_list)
```

I also do understand that `i` will take on each value of the list in this code:

```
for i in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
    print(i)
```

I am curious if the `in` operator used in the `for` loop is the same as the `in` operator used in the first code.

Comment: Duplicate or related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25573715/1639625

Comment: `in` and `for..in` are two different language constructs.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

They are the same concept but not the same operators.

In the `print(2 in some_list)` example, `in` is an operator that handles several different situations.  The [Python docs for the `in` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) give the details, which I paraphrase as follows: `x in y` calls `y.__contains__(x)` if `y` has a `__contains__` member function.  Otherwise, `x in y` tries iterating through `y.__iter__()` to find `x`, or calls `y.__getitem__(x)` if `__iter__` doesn't exist.  The complexity is to provide consistent membership testing for older code as well as newer code — `__contains__` is what you want if you're implementing your own classes.

In the `for` loop, `in` is just a marker that separates the loop-index variable from whatever you're looping over.  The [Python docs for the `for` loop](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#grammar-token-for_stmt) discuss the semantics, which I paraphrase as follows: whatever comes after `in` is evaluated at the beginning of a loop to provide an iterator.  The loop body then runs for each element of the iterator (barring `break` or other control-flow changes).  The `for` statement doesn't worry about `__contains__` or `__getitem__`.

**Edit** @Kelvin makes a good point: you can change the behaviour of `in` with respect to your own new-style classes (`class foo(object)`):

- To change `x in y`, [define `y.__contains__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__).
- To change `for x in y`, [define `y.__iter__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators).

Comment: upvote because you can change the behavior of the first kind of `in` by defining `__contains__`

Comment: The way it is worded implies to me that operator and keywords are seperate things although I would argue that it's nearly the same or that operators are also keyword.

Comment: @syntonym fixed - thanks :)

Comment: I found out that you could do `for...else`, so I felt that the `in` used in the `for` loop is essentially the same `in` as the one in the `print(2 in some_list)` example.

Comment: @Novice yes, `for`/`else` is a common source of confusion.  I recently discovered [this blog post](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/break_else.html#what-possible-use-is-the-current-behaviour) that I found helpful in that regard, and I hope my answer was useful to you!

Comment: I was guessing that `for x in some_list` would assign each element of `some_list` to `x` and `x in some_list` would act as the condition for the loop.

Comment: @Novice that was a very understandable guess :) .  The difference is subtle but real.  For example, `__contains__` is not called by the `for` loop.  Anyway, happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not the same. The `in` test like in your first example is a test for membership and returns a truth value. This `in` might be thought of as the sequential analogue of `==` or `is` (depending on how `__contains__` is implemented).

The `in` in your second example is part of the iteration grammar; it temporarily binds your selected variable `i` to each item in the iterable. This `in` might be thought of as the sequential analogue of `=`, the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

No, although they both use the same word they do different things. `in` is in both cases a syntax structure, e.g. it is not a name of a object and can't be changed. You can see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) the syntactic definition of each one. As you can see the names are hardcoded and have no relationship.