# Set Intersection with None

Tags: python, set, intersection, nonetype, operation

I am having trouble with set operation intersection.

Assume I have a list `A = [0,1,2,3]`, and an integer `B = 0`. When I check `if B in A:`, I am getting of course `True`.

But when `A` and `B` are as default equal to `None`, than I can't do the intersection operation of `A` and `B`.

I am looking for a way to do following without getting an error:

```
A = None
B = None

if B in A:
    raise KeyError('B in A')
```

Normally `A` is a python List and `B` is a string. But I need to set them to `None` as default, while they are arguments in my function; where they have to have a value of `None`.

PS: Getting `True` or `False` with the search algo. is not important. I just need to get `True` or `False`, so that I can arrange my error-raising.

Comment: Have you tried `A=[None]`?

Comment: Can't you set `A = set() if not A else A` at the start of your function?

Comment: They should be default None

Comment: Why can't you just check if they are `None`?

Comment: Because the point is checking if B in A, and they have to be None as default in my functions argument.

Comment: can't you do `if B in (A or [])`

Comment: Use a default value for A I would recommend, as you usually don't want mutable in your arguments set:
def fun(A=None, B=None):
  if A is None: A=[]
  return B in A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to set `A = []` instead of `A = None` (it's a reasonable value for something that will be a list eventually).

If `A` is argument to your function, be careful you don't write

```
def f(A=[])
```

but, instead

```
def f(A=None):
    if A is None:
       A = []
```

Comment: This looks nice, can I do also `A.isdisjoint(B)`?

Comment: @Icedkk no that's a set method. You said `A` is a list. If you want a set, why not use a set object. `A = set()`?

Comment: be careful: OP said he gets `None` from parameters. Don't use mutable default values in parameters.

Comment: @FHTMitchell you are right, well it creates a set afterwards... Anyway something similar like isdisjoint() to a list?

Comment: But why even use a `list` if you're going to turn it into a set, use a set from the beginning. `set(A).isdisjoint(...)` would work but isn't very efficient.

Comment: I just wanted to know if there is a function like isdisjoint also for lists, but ty.

Answer (score 1):

Why not try to check whether A or B is None itself?

```
A = None
B = None

if None not in [A, B] and B in A:
    print('B in A')
else:
    print('B or A is None, or B is not in A')
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try:

```
if B in (A or []):
```

so if `A` is `None` it tests against empty list and yields `False`

if `A` is an empty list, it will also test against the rightmost operand of `or` but the result will be the same.

Larger scope: if you have default values as `None` in your function:

```
def foo(A=None,B=None):
```

leave them as `None`, and change them in the function code so the default argument isn't mutable (["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)).

```
if A is None:
   A = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Continue using `None` as a default argument and then just set `a` to be the empty set `set` if it is `None` (I'm using lowercase argument names as per python convention):

```
def f(a=None, b=None):
   if a is None:
       a = set()

    if b in a:
        raise KeyError('b in a')

    if a.isdisjoint(other_set):
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
A = [None, 1, 2]
B = None

if B in A: # where A should be a list, it should be iterable
    print('done')
```

output

```
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way one would go about `None`-initialized arguments in a function is to assign them to a sane default value at the start of said function. I use type annotation just to show which kind of values can be passed:

```
from typing import List, Optional

def check_intersect(A: Optional[List[str]] = None, B: Optional[str] = None):
    if A is None:
        A = []
    if B in A:  # this can't fail any more 
        raise KeyError('B in A')
```

The `in` keyword (if it is not part of a for-loop of course..) requires a python object as its right-side argument that [offers a `__contains__()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38204487/962190) function, which `None` doesn't.