# How does the for keyword affect *in* expressions?

Tags: python, loops, parsing, boolean, expression

I understand that the python in operator is overloaded but I don't understand how the interpreter distinguishes different uses; Nor can I find Documentation to understand it.

Why is

```py
x = 1 
for x in (1,2,3):
    print(x)
```

not parsed as

```py
for true
```

Comment: [See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204342/python-in-keyword-in-expression-vs-in-for-loop)

Comment: `in` is not an operator in this context.  It's part of the `for` statement.  It separates the `for` variable(s) from the iterable.

Comment: @MarkMeyer thank you for that, that for the most part answered my question. Im guessing that once python encounters the for keyword, when it runs into *in* it no longer treats it like it would in other expressions? why is in used in for loops then? I feel like a different keyword would cause less confusion

Comment: This is *not* an `x in y` expression. The `for` results in a different production rule in the Python grammar.