# what is the significance of using list index in for loop of python?

Tags: python

I was trying to understand the following code

```
a=[0,1,2,3]
for a[-1] in a:
    print(a[-1])
```

I expected an infinite loop printing 3 but the output is quite incomprehensible as below

output:

```
0
1
2
2
```

can somebody Please explain the working of this code!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Mentally insert the line `a[-1] = i` inside that loop, where `i` is the current value in the iteration. `for a[-1] ...` assigns the iteration value to `a[-1]` on every iteration…

Comment: This is an interesting mental exercise. But I fail to see why anyone would write code like this.

Answer (score 1):

`in` keyword in `for` loop is different than other use cases.

in this `for` loop list returns an iterator and assign it to the variable in your case last element of list

to break your code this is what it is doing in background

```
for i in a:
    a[-1] = i
    print(a[-1])
```

reference: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement

and [Python 'in' keyword in expression vs. in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204342/python-in-keyword-in-expression-vs-in-for-loop)

Comment: In that case we should supposed to get  3 as the output in the last iteration but we are getting 2 as the output

Comment: @HarishRudroju Because in the penultimate iteration, `2` is assigned to `a[-1]`…