# Is there any easier way to write this comparison operator statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm fairly new to Python. I have the following if statement:

```
if(userGuess == "0" or userGuess == "1" or userGuess == "2" or userGuess == "3" or userGuess == "4" or userGuess == "5" or userGuess == "6" or userGuess == "7" or userGuess == "8" or userGuess == "9"):
    print("\n>>>error: cannot use integers\n")
    continue
```

Basically, the loop will reset if the user inputs any numbers. Is there any way to write this statement to make it a little more efficient? (i.e less code and cleaner)

Comment: Try `if userGuess.isnumeric():` - see [`str.isnumeric()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.isnumeric).

Comment: What about numbers > 9?

Comment: Is `userGuess` limited to a single character?

Comment: As a note on examples, `continue` can't be used outside of a loop. Its best to post a running example. In your case, assigning a value to `userGuess` and leaving out the `continue`.

Comment: thanks for all the help. i didn't know you can int() with a str that's a number

Comment: If `userGuess` is any string of digits greater than 0 length, then `int` works. Suppose its `User1234`, `int` would fail, but the guess would contain digits. I don't know what you want in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
possibilities = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

if userGuess in possibilities:
    #do something
```

Or alternatively, if you are ok with doing a comparison with integers instead you could do the following:

```
if userGuess < 10:
    #do something
```

Comment: could you explain how the loop if userGuess in possibilities: works?

Comment: Sure, no problems. The if statement is followed by a conditional check (which if evaluated to true, executes the next indented block of code). 
The use of the keyword in, is best explained already by this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38204487). It simply checks if the value of userGuess is inside the list of items in possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
nums = [str(i) for i in range(10)] # gets a list of nums from 0 to 9    

if userGuess in nums:
    print("Num found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `userGuess` is a string and can be other than a single character,

```
if(any(c.isdigit() for c in userGuess):
    ....
```

if the guess should be exactly one character, you can

```
if(len(userGuess) != 1 or userGuess in "0123456789"):
    ....
```

or

```
if(len(userGuess) != or userGuess.isdigit()):
    ...
```

Come to think of it, `isdigit` is the better way to go. Suppose the user entered the Bengali number `৩`? `৩.isdigit()` is `True`.