# Python 'in' operator with 'for' loop and with 'if' statement

Tags: python, if-statement, for-in-loop

I am using python **in** operator with **for** loop and with **if** statement. My question is how is **in** implemented, that it behaves differently in this two cases: it iterates when using **for** loop and it checks if some element exists when using with **if** statement? Does this depend on implementation of **for** and **if**?

```
    for i in x:
        #iterates

    if i in x:
        #checks weather i in x or not
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword "in" in python solves different purposes based on "for" and "if". please look at [this related link in stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25573715/mysterious-for-loop-in-python) for more clarity

Answer (score 2):

Membership testing with `in` is implemented via the method `__contains__` (see [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations)). The different behaviour comes from the keyword before, `for` and `if` in your case.

Iteration with `for` is implemented such, that the method `next` is called and its return value is written to the iteration variable as long as the condition after the key word `for` is true. Membership testing in general is just a condition.

**Code**

```
A in B
```

**Execution**

```
B.__contains__(A)  # returns boolean
```

---

**Code**

```
for A in B :
    # Body
```

**Execution**

```
A = B.next()
if B.__contains__(A) :
    # Body

A = B.next()
if B.__contains__(A) :
    # Body

# ...

A = B.next()
if B.__contains__(A) :
    # B.next() throws "StopIteration" if there is no more element
```

Comment: If `B.next()` returns `A`, then there is no need for `if B.__contains__(A):`. Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In many languages you'll find keywords that have multiple uses. This is simply an example of that. It's probably more helpful to think in terms of *statements* than thinking about the `in` keyword like an operator.

The statement  `x in y` is a boolean-valued statement taking (assuming `y` is some appropriate collection) `True` if and only if the value of `x` is in the collection `y`. It is implemented with the `__contains__` member function of `y`.

The statement `for x in y:` starts a loop, where each iteration `x` takes a different value from the collection `y`. This is implemented using the `__iter__` member function of `y` and `__next__` on the resulting iterator object.

There are other statements where the `in` keyword can appear, such as list comprehension or generator comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

The `in` keyword is an operator usually:

```
print(2 in [1, 2, 3])  # True
if 3 in range(7, 20):
   print('3 in range!')
```

It corresponds to the [`object.__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) special method. The expression `a in b` corresponds to `type(b).__contains__(a)`. Note that both `a` and `b` are names that are looked up.

In a `for` statement, `in` is *not* an operator. It is part of the `for .. in ..` syntax and separates the loop variable *name* from the iterable.

```
for thing in range(20):
    print(thing)  # thing is something else on each step
```

Note that `for a in b` only `b` is a name that is looked up. `a` is a name to bind to, similar to an assignment statement.

---

Python syntax has several constructs where the leading keyword defines the meaning of following keywords. For example, the `as` keyword has a different meaning in `import` and `with`:

```
# as aliases ExitStack
from contextlib import ExitStack as ContextStack

# as holds the result of ContextStack().__enter__()
with ContextStack() as stack:
    ...
```

It helps to think about such keywords not by *implementation* but by *meaning*. For example, `a in b` always means that "`a` is contained by `b`".

Comment: @Nane please upvote answers that help you and accept the one that answers your question best.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `for...in` is something different from just `in`.

`for x in y` iterates over `y`.

`if x in y` calls `y.__contains__(x)`.